# Contextual menu on windows taskbar not reacting

Tags: windows-10, ssd, taskbar

When Windows starts, and I right click on any icon on the taskbar, selecting any option, it works, but windows shows no signal of reaction. The menu stays frozen as if nothing happened, for a long time. There is no way of telling if it acknowledged the click until the program starts (sometimes never starts, as if no click were made).

What I do expect, like on other PCs with SSD, and even older processors with less memory, is for the menu to disappear after the click, with much faster reaction times.

There is any way to diagnose or fix it?

- OS: Windows 10 1903 - fully updated
- i7 7700 - with latest video driver.
- 32 GB DDR4
- WD green SSD

[Screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d782w.png)

Comment: That's normal. The task bar is shown before explorer (and all the startup programs) is fully loaded.

Comment: @DavidPostill I work with a similar PC with a Samsung EVO SSD, and it reacts instantly. No delay. May it be that the WD SSD is too slow?

Comment: Check the disk S.M.A.R.T. data, if nothing then check Windows integrity with [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc SMART data doesn't seems to have a problem https://imgur.com/YWA0U3S

Comment: sfc /scannow doesn't finds any problem.

Comment: Looking good. Try now to boot in Safe mode and see if the problem disappears.